# How to Iterate through many columns in csv file and save the data into dictionary of dictionaries (json format)?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I have a problem to Iterate through many columns in csv file and  save the data into 3 separate dictionary of dictionaries which are tflist = {}, tflist1 = {} and tflist2 = {} by making filtration by each item in a list_Item list. I am looking to get all times for all ip-addresses for every 6 hours (6*60*60 =21600 sec) for each item in "list_Item" list and save the data for each iteration into the three dictionaries mentioned before. This means that I am looking to make filtration of the data through each item in "list_Item"  and every 6 hours for each IP Address and save the data into three separate dictionary of dictionaries where the number of items in "list_Item" is 3.

When I ran the code below, I got an empty dictionary for the first dictionary "tflist". I need your help in figuring out what is the problem in the code below.

Please note the number of dictionaries (not only 3 dictionaries) can be more than three dictionaries based on the number of items in "list_Item" which can be more than 3 items. I would be happy if you can help me to fix this code to let's work for any case (any number of items in "list_Item" list).

```
import csv

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import operator 

from datetime import datetime as dt

from pandas import DataFrame

import time

import datetime

import math


fn3 = 'screenviewclean.1.csv'

f2 = open(fn3,"r")

filereader = csv.reader(f2)

tflist = {}

tflist1 = {}

tflist2 = {}

i = 0

list_Item =  ["CompanyProfile","CreateCompanyProfile","ClaimCompany"]


for line in filereader:

    i+=1  
    sec= line [10]
    IpAddress = line [2]
    timeStamp = line [6]
    time = timeStamp[11:13]+ timeStamp[13:19]
    View_Screen = line [7] 
    def fun3_SctreenView (Item):
        for y in range(1,4):
            if Item[y-1] in View_Screen:
                if i>1:
                    for x in range(1,82):
                        if x == 1:
                            if float(line[10]) <= float(x*21600):
                                if x in tflist.keys():
                                    if IpAddress in tflist[x].keys():
                                        tflist[x][IpAddress].append(str(time))
                                    else:
                                        tflist[x][IpAddress] = [str(time)]
                                else:
                                    temp = {}
                                    temp[IpAddress] = [str(time)]
                                    tflist[x] = temp
                        if x>=2:
                            if float(line[10]) > float((x-1)*21600) and float(line[10]) <= float(x * 21600):
                                if x in tflist.keys():
                                    if IpAddress in tflist[x].keys():
                                        tflist[x][IpAddress].append(str(time))
                                    else:
                                        tflist[x][IpAddress] = [str(time)]
                                else:
                                    temp = {}
                                    temp[IpAddress] = [str(time)]
                                    tflist[x] = temp

fun3_SctreenView(list_Item)
```

These are three rows of the csv file:

```
Unnamed: 0  lastLoggedVersion   IpAddress   deviceId    deviceOS    userId  timeStamp   screenName  userType    doc.id  seconds

0   1.6.0.1 192.168.0.77    7612F62D-E392-4269-B49B-4F1214AA3888    iOS13.6.1   5U1XW8wkoqUPCTGhC1ni9Whinvt1    2020-11-13 22:28:55.029000+00:00    StudentProfile  student 00mrvPyS9Y2Al9iTN1vw    1231534.547

2   1.6.1.44    10.0.2.16   40a4dc7cb837fdec    Android10   27lFw6EnfbYFsU3F8AEejYGQRRl1    2020-11-12 21:28:00.998000+00:00    CompanySettings company 01dMOvAgsRTPSWXTDXIh    1141480.516

6   1.6.0.43    192.168.87.241  ec62706b2834bfcc    Android9    7XBtY5ZDxcPWYF7sGECDZxnH71b2    2020-11-12 21:41:33.126000+00:00    DiscoverCompanies   student 064kDvawK8cJoRl5if9d    1142292.644
```

Comment: Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.